# What all dependency in the get.k3s.io script need to be edited to download k3s locally

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

Currently I am using command `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io` to download k3s. The script **[get.k3s.io](https://get.k3s.io/)** is using below third party internet calls to URLs :

```
GITHUB_URL=https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases
STORAGE_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/k3s-ci-builds
```

I want to avoid the above calls to URLs and want same k3s package to be stored locally in my personal github project location and want to download/read it from there instead. Can some one let me know the steps/procedure to edit this script and download and store k3s locally ? What all dependency need to be changed/edited here ?

Answer (score 0):

## Read the fine [manual](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/)

In addition to that fully scripted online download, installation and configuration method K3S also provides a more conventional installation method.

Follow that:

> ## Options for installation from binary
>
> As stated, the installation script is primarily concerned with configuring K3s to run as a service. If you choose to not use the script, ***you can run K3s simply by downloading the binary from our [release page](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/releases/latest), placing it on your path, and executing it.*** The K3s binary supports the following commands: